# How do I manually assign bytes to a long in Kotlin?

Tags: java, kotlin

I am trying to do something like this in `Kotlin`:

```
val top : Long = 1000000_1000000_1000000_1000000_1000000_1000000_1000000
```

In `Java` it looks like this:

```
long TOP = 1000000_1000000_1000000_1000000_1000000_1000000_1000000L;
```

The `Java` version works just fine, in Kotlin I get an error:

```
The value is out of range
```

Does anyone have an idea on how to do it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://github.com/denkspuren/BitboardC4/blob/master/BitboardDesign.md#generate-valid-moves I want to implement this bitboard design for a project. I got everything except the last part working so far.

Comment: @AnimeshSahu but why does it work in Java and not in Kotlin?

Comment: Apologizes, I didn't read the question properly (I thought you wanted to store that as a number, not a binary) :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do like below in `Kotlin`, prefix `0b` for `Long` representation.

```
val top : Long = 0b1000000_1000000_1000000_1000000_1000000_1000000_1000000
```

For more info on this, please check the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html)